# Evitar el paso a el formulario anterior sino ha cerrado el actual, vb Devexpress

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, devexpress

Tengo un `form` en el cual se ingresa información, es como una ventana emergente.

Existe alguna función que me impida para el formulario anterior solo con clic, el problema es que se pasa solo con clic y queda abierta, espero haberme hecho entender.

[image: e aquí la ventana]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes abrir un formulario de dos formas:

Formulario.Show() : abre el formulario como una ventana normal. Por lo tanto, cuando está abierta, todavía puedes trabajar con otros formularios abiertos (por ejemplo, cambiar entre ellos).

Formulario.ShowDialog() : abre el formulario con instancia modal, por lo tanto, hasta que no  cierras el formulario no podrás acceder a los otros formularios.

Comment: Miguel era exactamente lo que buscaba, he usado el Formulario.ShowDialog() y funciona perfecto...